# added information in data table are not being calculated (frequency)

Tags: excel, vba

I created a table with a lot of dates so i can have the delay between these dates and the date of today.

Now I wanted to regroup the delays in 0-30 days, 30-60 days, 60-90 days.

The problem is when I add a new date in my table, it doesnt calculate this date. It only calculate what I have selected.

i'm new in excel and im searching a lot without finding much answers, thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you add screenshots to better explain your problem?

Comment: and add the code you have so far

Answer (score -1):

You can this formula (assuming that the dates in your table are start in cell A2) (i'm also assuming this doesn't have any cases out of your buckets)

=IF( AND(today()-A2<=90, today()-A2>=60), "60-90 Days", if( today()-A2>30, "30-60 Days", "0-30 Days"))

You may have to change some of the equal than to suit the specifics, since your request has some overlap (for example, 30 days would be in two buckets: 0-30 & 30-60)

Comment: This should answer your question, unless there's additional details missing. If not can you please mark this as the answer?